# Programmatically set percentage width/height of a view dependent upon available space

Tags: kotlin, android-layout, user-interface, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to use `ConstraintSet`'s `constrainPercentWidth` or `constrainPercentHeight` to set the dimensions of a view dependent upon whether the screen has more space width-wise or height-wise. Equivalently, I'd like to use the smaller of the two values as the width and height for the view. The pseudocode might look something like this.

```
    val cs = ConstraintSet()
    //...
    if (widthIsSmaller)
        cs.constrainPercentWidth(viewId, percent)
    else
        cs.constrainPercentHeight(viewId, percent)

    cs.setDimensionRatio(viewId, "1:1")
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get the height and view in pixels in the main activity's onCreate.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
      WindowMetrics windowMetrics = activity.getWindowManager().getCurrentWindowMetrics();
        Insets insets = windowMetrics.getWindowInsets()
                .getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars());
        width = windowMetrics.getBounds().width() - insets.left - insets.right;
       height = windowMetrics.getBounds().height()-insets.top-insets.bottom;
    } else {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        width= displayMetrics.widthPixels;
        height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    }
```

And then set the contrains as

```
val percentage = 0.5 // it would take half of the width or height

val smallerDimension = minOf(width,height)

val desiredDimension = (smallerDimension * percentage).toInt()

if ( width <= height) {
    constraintSet.constrainPercentWidth(viewId, (desiredDimension.toFloat() / screenWidth))
    constraintSet.constrainPercentHeight(viewId, 1.0f)
} else {
    constraintSet.constrainPercentWidth(viewId, 1.0f)
    constraintSet.constrainPercentHeight(viewId, (desiredDimension.toFloat() / screenHeight))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is great, but is there a solution that doesn't use deprecated code?

Comment: @AldenBernitt i have edited the answer and include the version check , please upvote and mark accepted if it helpet you:)